# Which is the corresponding word of the x mode on open files in C language?

Tags: c

Which is the corresponding word of the x mode on open file in c language? I have searched this question on the internet for a while, but have no answer. How can I get relevant info? Please help me, thanks!

Comment: What is "the x mode"? Do you mean the Unix/Linux executable bit? If so, why do you think C cares about whether something is executable? What are you trying to do? This is an unclear question.

Comment: @underscore_d  I want to know what the full name of this word 'x' is, for example, I know that 'a' mode corresponding the word 'append', how about 'x' mode?

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't know C11 added that. But maybe you can see how the question is quite vague as written. If you had linked to a piece of documentation saying something like 'This shows that `x` is one of the available modes but does not explain what it does/stands for', I wouldn't have been confused. :)

Comment: @underscore_d I am sorry about that. Next time I will try to explain my questions more clear, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

From the C11 standard, **[7.21.5.3§5] The `fopen` function** (emphasis mine):

> Opening  a  file  with  **exclusive  mode**  (`'x'` as  the  last  character  in  the `mode` argument) fails  if  the  file  already  exists  or  cannot  be  created. Otherwise,  the  file  is  created  with exclusive  (also  known  as  non-shared)  access  to  the  extent  that  the  underlying  system supports exclusive access.

So `x` is indeed the abbreviation of "exclusive mode".

Comment: you are right! **exclusive** is the corresponding word!

Answer (score 1):

The latest C standard C11 provides a new mode “x” which is exclusive create-and-open mode. Mode “x” can be used with any “w” specifier, like “wx”, “wbx”. When x is used with w, fopen() returns NULL if file already exists or could not open.
C11 program that doesn’t overwrite an existing file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "wx");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        puts("Couldn't open file or file already exists");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        fputs("stack overflow", fp);
        puts("Done");
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So the 'x' is the word that exclusive's abbreviation form?